# how to display different wizard view for one2many field than the original view?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12

I'm using a module for Odoo documents management, in the view of the main directory there is an one2many field for sub-directories and it point's to the same model so while creating it's open a wizard exactly like the form which it locates, I need to hide some fields form this wizard and add some new fields related to sub-directories only, how can I do that, this the code

```
 class Directory(models.Model):

_name = 'muk_dms.directory'
_description = "Directory"

_inherit = [
    'muk_utils.mixins.hierarchy',
    'muk_security.mixins.access_rights',
    'muk_dms.mixins.thumbnail',
]

_order = "name asc"

_parent_store = True
_parent_name = "parent_directory"

_parent_path_sudo = False
_parent_path_store = False

_name_path_context = "dms_directory_show_path"

#----------------------------------------------------------
# Database
#----------------------------------------------------------

name = fields.Char(
    string="Name", 
    required=True,
    index=True)

is_root_directory = fields.Boolean(
    string="Is Root Directory", 
    default=False,
    help="""Indicates if the directory is a root directory. A root directory has a settings object,
        while a directory with a set parent inherits the settings form its parent.""")

root_storage = fields.Many2one(
    comodel_name='muk_dms.storage',  
    string="Root Storage",
    ondelete='restrict')

storage = fields.Many2one(
    compute='_compute_storage',
    comodel_name='muk_dms.storage', 
    string="Storage",
    ondelete='restrict',
    auto_join=True,
    readonly=True,
    store=True)

parent_directory = fields.Many2one(
    comodel_name='muk_dms.directory', 
    domain="""[('permission_create', '=', True)]""",
    context="{'dms_directory_show_path': True}",
    string="Parent Directory",
    ondelete='restrict',
    auto_join=True,
    index=True)
```

as it shown in above code the last field is get the data form the same model, how can i display wizard with different fields 
Thanks in advance,

Comment: you need to use debug mode(insert `?debug=1` between `web` and `#id` in url), enter wizard and click debug item on the wizard and edit view (I don't know the exact name in English ) to check the view_id. Then create a xml doc to inherit that view and replace those fileds.

Comment: find key work `name="inherit_id"` in odoo source. there are bunches of examples.

Comment: Try to pass [form_view_ref](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/stock/views/stock_picking_views.xml#L307) in context.